# [ROS2] Why rclcpp node now() function returns 0 in node construtor?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm calling client now function while constructing the node, but this value is still zero:

```
now().seconds(); // 0 always (only in constructor) for some reason
```

Is it intended behaviour? I'm using simulation time. Later, when calling same exact function in a method, it returns correct time value.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356733/%5Bros2%5D-why-rclcpp-node-now()-function-returns-0-in-node-construtor?/) by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2020-07-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Time is zero in the node constructor when using simulated time because the clock has not received the current time yet.

The clock gets the simulated time through a subscription to a `/clock` topic. Subscription callbacks are called by the executor, but the node must be constructed before it can be added to an executor. That's why simulated time will always be zero in the constructor.

I'm guessing you'd like record the initial time when a node starts. I would recommend doing that by checking if the time is zero when the node starts, and if so [register a time jump callback](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/549988277385fcfde410e419172a874cad2413c8/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/clock.hpp#L129-L132). When the new simulated time is received the time jump callback will be called and the initial time can be recorded.

You might also be interested in the [Clock and Time ROS 2 design doc](http://design.ros2.org/articles/clock_and_time.html) which describes how simulated time works.

In particular:

> If time has not been set it will return zero if nothing has been received. A time value of zero should be considered an error meaning that time is uninitialized.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) on 2020-07-14**:
Thank you!